# How to reload tableView after regaining internet from a button

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, appdelegate, nsnotificationcenter

I set all my error handling code for when the user loses the internet connection in `tableViewController`. Say the user exits the cell and then comes back, the `ProgressHUD`(custom activity indicator) will pop up from `viewDidAppear` and no cell will be shown because they don't have any wifi. After that let's say the user regains the connection, but the `tableView` is still empty, I have a button in the navigation bar that will reload the data from `UIApplicationDidBecomeActive`, but the only problem is that the tableView is not getting updated there still no cells showing up.

```
@IBAction func tableReload(_ sender: Any) {              
    if reach.connection == .wifi || reach.connection == .cellular {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(reloadTable(note:)), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)

    }else {
        ProgressHUD.showError("Can not reload if there is no internet connection")// activity indicator from a library
    }
}

@objc func reloadTable(note: NSNotification) {
    let reachability = note.object as! Reachability

    if reachability.connection == .wifi || reachability.connection == .cellular{
        ProgressHUD.showSuccess("Wifi is good")
        self.tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
        self.tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }else {
        tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
        tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        ProgressHUD.show("Can not reload with no internet connection")
    }
}
```

Comment: `tableView.reloadData()` will merely invoke the data source methods like `numberOfRows` and `cellForRow(at:)`. So if the data source relies on a model, then that model would need to refetch data from the server and then do a reload of data on the table view

Comment: @user1046037 okay I'll see what I can do

Answer (score 0):

```
@objc func reloadTable(note: NSNotification) {
    let reachability = note.object as! Reachability

    if reachability.connection == .wifi || reachability.connection == .cellular{
        ProgressHUD.showSuccess("Wifi is good")
        self.tableView.isScrollEnabled = true
        self.tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        self.fetchData() // call fetch Method
    }else {
        tableView.isScrollEnabled = false
        tableView.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        ProgressHUD.show("Can not reload with no internet connection")
    }
}

func fetchData() {
  // Assign data to TableView's DataSource
  // Now reload the TableView 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After regaining your internet connection update Data Model (data you want to show in table) then call  `tableView.reloadData()`

Answer (score 0):

Simply Reloading doesn't get your data back. Fetch your data from the server (ie: Call API), if it success load your array/dictionary to pass data to tableViewDataSource and then reload tableView Data....!

Example:

```
Alamofire.request(urlString).responseJSON { (response) in

if response.result.isSuccess
{
  completion(response.result.value as AnyObject?, "", true)

  // pass values to array/Dictionary
   let restDict = response.result

  // reload TableView
   tableView.reloadData()

 }
 else
 {
    completion(nil, "", false)
 }
}
```

Comment: It would have been great only if I wasn't using switfsoup.Thank you for the response though.